# file_put_contents no me guarda en el servidor

Tags: php, base-de-datos, hosting

```
file_put_contents($filepath,$imagen);
```

no me guarda en mi servidor del hosting, pero sí en mi directorio de la computara si lo inserto la ruta correspondiente.
¿qué puede no haber hecho para que me guarde en el servidor?

Comment: Cuáles son los permisos de la carpeta destino en el servidor? Prueba a poner 777 para ver si funciona, y luego los adecuas a lo que necesites

Comment: Actualmente tiene 755, lo cambié a 777 y tampoco me guarda

Comment: que debo configurar en mi php o servidor?

Comment: Si no es problema de permisos quizás este enlace pueda ayudarte [https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/]

Comment: me dice que la página no existe :(

Comment: Que raro, es el enlace dado en la respuesta de esta página [https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/508849-recursive-write-permissions/]

Answer (score 1):

Econntré la solución en esta página:  http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php
mi error era que

```
$filepath = "http://www.example.com/AfuncServidor/imagenes/".$nombreFoto;
```

cuando debería ser:

```
$filepath =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/AfuncServidor/imagenes/".$nombreFoto
```

eso era mi error, muchas gracias a todos y espero que le sirva esta info a otros novatos como yo :D :D

Comment: Yo quiero que me guarde en la computadora del usuario final, como seria? lo estoy llamando por ajax